# Make cloning from personal git server authenticated

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, git

I have followed [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-http-git-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/) tutorial for having a personal git server, over Internet.

Everything works perfect, except cloning is public on Internet. What I want is just users in /var/www/html/git/passwd be able to clone from my repos.

I know there should be a little change in nginx (or am I mistaken?). Please guide or hint me through.

Thanks.